# Global object in C# Windows service with WCF interface

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Windows service that has a WCF interface. Now as this WCF interface is hosted from the Service application I'm having some problems in defining my core object as a global variable.

I have created the main object in a library currently as a singleton with a static instance member. The WCF service will interface with the static instance. While this works fine, I'm not a particular fan of called MyServiceBase.Instance in every single method. What is the most elegant way to do this?

Preferably I would instantiate my object in the program `Main` and have it available through my application. In my old Visual Basic 6.0 days I would just declare it as a global static.

Answer (score 0):

In your MyServiceBase class do this:

```
public class MyServiceBase  {

   static MyServiceBase  _instance;

   public MyServiceBase () {
      if ( _instance == null ) {
         // do the initialization
         _instance = this; 
      }
   } 
}
```

Then the initialization consist in calling the constructor without even storing the reference anywhere.

```
// just create a new object which causes the initialization code to execute
new MyServiceBase ();
```

Now you don't have to do MyServiceBase.Instance on every call.

Comment: Why the downvote? Am I not understanding the question correctly?

Comment: I didn't downvote, looks ok to me, wonder if there are any other "best practices though", this will at least solve the Instance problem.

Comment: I personally use this method... but that doesn't mean it's the best way of doing it. You could read through some of these answers to get more ideas : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943311/c-sharp-singleton-pattern-with-triggerable-initialization